# I tried to work with Fragments using supportFragmentManager, but the add method is not working, showing error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I tried to work with Fragments using supportFragmentManager, but the add method is not working, showing error(none of the supported functions can be called with the arguments supplied). I used add function that requires container Id and Fragment, **Fragment** colored red.

My fragment, haven't editted yet

```kotlin
package com.example.ftcapp

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup


// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [CurrenciesFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class CurrenciesFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currencies, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment CurrenciesFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            CurrenciesFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

```kotlin
package com.example.ftcapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.FrameLayout
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied and Fragment argument colored red
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragment_container, CurrenciesFragment)
            .commit()
    }
}
```

https://ibb.co/vPWpP6t

My fragment extends andoridx.fragment.app.fragment

Main activity layout file with fragment container

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_currencies" />

    <!--<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />-->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add` requires an instance of Fragment

Change `CurrenciesFragment` (type or an instance of companion object) to `CurrenciesFragment()` (instantiation)